# Xamarin Android - Moving Image Background

Tags: android, xamarin, animation

I'm trying to make a moving background animation like this one
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXwQjUwEa40 but in Xamarin Android C#.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can also check this doc: [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows) by official.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image with .gif format in Xamarin

```
<Image Source="XXX.gif" IsAnimationPlaying="True" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```